# Autofilter by DisplayText in DevExpress

Tags: winforms, filter, devexpress

I have a calculated numeric field in a grid. I use a custom editor for it. All filter operations in Filter editor work well but the auto filter row filters according to the value and not the display text. I know that I can set FilterMode to DisplayText but then this is also used for comparisons etc. So, I need to use FilterMode DisplayText for the auto filter, Value for everything else. Is this possible? I have already a lot of code in the custom grid class, so it would be ok to have an additional event handler or another workaround.

**EDIT**

I store e.g. prices in euro and I display them differently depending on the user's settings. So, e.g. I have stored a value 100 and I need to display "234 abc". When I set `FilterMode=DisplayText`, I can't compare the actual value with e.g. `>` and `<`. Currently, I use `FilterMode=Value` and I convert the displayed value in the filter editor for filtering. The only problem is with `StartsWith` i.e. auto filter and with `=` because of rounding. How could I fix that?

Comment: You need to provide more information. The comparisons for example. You can easily throw a custom event for some of these things. It would just be important to know why you can't use FilterMode as DisplayText. For example, you could set the filter mode to display text for the auto filter. Then when something is selected instead of now looking at the display text you could get the underlying data source's object and get the property you need.

Comment: I store e.g. prices in euro and I display them differently depending on the user's settings. So, e.g. I have stored a value 100 and I need to display "234 abc". When I set `FilterMode=DisplayText`, I can't compare the actual value with e.g. `>` and `<`. Currently, I use `FilterMode=Value` and I convert the displayed value in the filter editor for filtering. The only problem is with `StartsWith` i.e. auto filter and with `=` because of rounding. How could I fix that?

Comment: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/clsDevExpressDataFilteringFunctionOperatortopic

Comment: I am familiar with that... it doesn't help

Comment: How would you imagine the user filtering? Using the typical autofilter row? I would suggest maybe removing auto filtering. Then on grid key down you can track the user's key strokes. On the keydown event you could capture and save the characters entered. You can then apply your custom logic by analyzing the entered text and then comparing it to whatever property in your data source you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my issue... As I have no control on how exactly the values are filtered and I had couple of problems with filtering, I converted my bound columns to unbound columns. I removed the editors making the conversions and replaced them by unbound expressions with custom functions + display format. Not really the solution I was searching for but it works for all kinds of filtering.